# Amazon S3 multipart upload in nodejs using REST API

Tags: rest, node.js, upload, amazon-s3, multipart

I'm trying to find some example code that utilizes node.JavaScript, Express.
I have gone through the some examples with knox but I did not found the multipart upload.

Can someone point me to a gist or other example that contains this kind of information?

Please help I will look forward for your suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The AwsSum library can do all of S3's Multipart operations. It's been a part of the library since inception.

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum/

The following operations have been implemented, so you should be able to use them to complete your uploads in a number of operations:

- ListMultipartUploads
- InitiateMultipartUpload
- CompleteMultipartUpload
- AbortMultipartUpload
- UploadPart
- UploadPartCopy
- ListParts

So that's about everything you need. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pull request to the knox repository that implements such functionality. It has not been merged, so it may not work properly. But they have the link to S3's doc about how to implement the multipart upload, if that would help you.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/pull/17

Comment: means i can't use knox or is there any way to stick up with it. If not then any other solution to implement the same. Because i have gone through link you provided but no solution.

Comment: Well, you can give it a try. Just download/fork knox and put the code from the pull request in it. Then make sure it works for what you need. It looks like it does a lot of heavy moving for you, so should at least make it easier for you.

Comment: i am not able to get the expresso for the knox can you help me?

Comment: expresso? That's a testing framework.. not quite sure what the issue is. You are probably better off posting in the pull request so that the original author can guide you along.